# How to keep task's priority after retrying?

Tags: celery

In `celery`, how to keep task's original priority after retrying?

My task after retrying does not have priority of the original task anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this you could pass original priority into `retry` call

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def task_to_retry(self):
    try:
        raise RuntimeError()
    except RuntimeError:
        self.retry(priority=self.request.delivery_info.get('priority'))
```